# Python: Scan all sites of a website for specific URLs

Tags: python

I want to scan my forum for specific links. All links look like this: `http://www.vbulletinxyz-forum.tld/forum/showthread.php?t=17590`. Only the thread-number at the end of the link changes.

Currently I am using the following code, but it only works for one specific URL, not all threads of the forum. How would I have to change the code to let it scan all threads?

```
import urllib
mypath = "http://vbulletin-forumxyz.tld/forum/showthread.php?t=1"
mylines = urllib.urlopen(mypath).readlines()
for item in mylines:
    if "http://specific.tld" in item:
        print item[item.index("http://specific.tld"):]
```

Comment: Try to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Try `re.match()`. Since I do not know much about `re`, you can read the link for further information.

Answer (score 1):

1. either by trying all thread numbers
2. or by using a spider which follows links (and discovers new threads)

(1) is easy to implement but probably not all thread numbers (t) are existent. So there will be a lot of 404 requests.

(2) take a look at [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html)

update (1): here is how it can be done in principle. Note that a) the url you provided is not reachable (dummy) so i did not test it and b) its python 3.X

```
import urllib.request
import time


def mypath(t):
    return "http://vbulletin-forumxyz.tld/forum/showthread.php?t={}".format(t)


for t in range(2):
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(mypath(t))

    # check status code
    if conn.getcode() != 200:
        continue

    mylines = conn.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
    for item in mylines:
        if "http://specific.tld" in item:
            print(item)

   # avoid fetching to fast (you might get banned otherwise)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: i would prefer (1) and the script should just skip 404 and try the next number. but would you tell me?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I get the following errors and warnings (tried to run it https://rextester.com/l/python3_online_compiler): https://pastebin.com/AcdrhFbr

I also tried it on and got this:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    if "http://specific.tld" in item:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```

Comment: i added the decoding of the string assuming its UTF-8. I suggest to look into beautiful soup. Its not as complex as scrapy but is much more robust for what you are doing: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: thanks. with your updated code i got: https://pastebin.com/WnbvDfYu

will check out beautiful soup but i am not a coder, so i guess it's too hard for me to do from scratch.

Comment: that means that your website is encoded in something different then UTF-8 :)

Comment: Right, windows-1251 :)

Now the script doesn't give any results. But if I use a thread-number instead of `{}` it works (more or less as I get dublicate results). So, it seems that `{}` doesn't work and it doesn't check the other threads.

Comment: {} is just a placeholder. `mypath(123)` just returns `http://vbulletin-forumxyz.tld/forum/showthread.php?t=123`

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works and checks threads from 0 to 400,000.

```
import urllib.request
import time
import codecs

def mypath(t):
    return "http://www.someforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t={}".format(t)


for t in range(0,400000):
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(mypath(t))

    # check status code
    if conn.getcode() != 200:
        continue

    mylines = conn.read().decode('windows-1251').splitlines()

    for item in mylines:
        if "http://someurl.tld" in item:
            print(item)

   # avoid fetching to fast (you might get banned otherwise)
   # time.sleep(0.5)
```